# How to resolve memory issue in Yii2 Kartik ExportMenu

Tags: php, memory, yii2

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Allowed memory size of 373293056 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 163840 bytes)
```

I have already look in to similar issues. Most of them say to improve the code so that program should not consume much memory. My question is related to Yii2 where I have using kartik-v `ExportMenu::widget` . Since I am providing `ExportMenu` an `ActiveDataProvider` so, I do not have an option to improve code.
My code looks like this

```
$query = MyModel::find()->with(['A', 'B'])->alias('q');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => ['id' => SORT_DESC],
                'attributes' => [
                    'id',
                    ...,
                    'created_at' => [
                        'asc' => ['q.id' => SORT_ASC],
                        'desc' => ['q.id' => SORT_DESC],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

And in view.

```
<?= ExportMenu::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => $gridColumns,
                'filename' => "fname" . date('Y_m_d_h_m_s')
            ]);
```

Please suggest a solution to fix this inside Yii2

Comment: If your data are only few rows, the problem might be in your code outside of `ExportMenu`. To export many rows you can try setting `batchSize` property of `ExportMenu`. If that doesn't help you will have to create exports in other way. `ExportMenu` uses PhpSpreadsheet which builds the spreadsheet in memory. That's not exactly best way to create large exports.

Comment: What is the size of the result set - both rows and total column length? I see options to limit columns, perhaps that can help as well.

Comment: @MichalHynčica I tried with batch size 10 and then 5, same error is happening. Only ~1500 records are there in GridView.